# Shared Exchange Calendars on iPhone

Tags: iphone, exchange, calendar

I have my work exchange account synced with my iPhone 3G. The problem is that I do not see the calendars that are shared with me (i.e. My boss's). Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: The iOS system doesn't do any sharing or serving of calendars. It consumes calendar data over the air using CalDAV and exchange ActiveSync. This is going to require some major editing to address how your workflow might use an exchange server.

Comment: It's possible though sometimes a bit flaky - see this question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152243/how-to-view-public-exchange-calendars-from-ical

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes that the people whose data you wish to access are willing to give you the login information.

The IPhone accepts multiple exchange setups, the solution is to create a new second setup using your boss's details, and turn off whats not required, IE you dont need to see his emails, so you just leave reminders and calender on etc.

the downside to this is the obvious security implications, as you could easily turn on the email and view others information.

But as a workaround, its the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

That's a limitation of the iPhone currently.  There used to be an app called [iExchange Calendar](http://www.apptism.com/apps/iexchange) that would let you view them but it was pulled from the App Store.

Comment: This is not a iPhone Limitation, this is a activesync limitation.

Comment: What I _meant_ was that the iPhone once had an answer to the problem by using iExchange, but that is no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, iPhones can subscribe to ics files shared on the Internet. Because of this you can use this as a solution in some cases. Exchange 2010 has the ability to publish full calendar detail to ics files but the Administrator usually has to allow it by running a powershell script.

This article describes the tradeoffs in security in doing this. http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2011/02/16/3412010.aspx

This article describes the powershell commands for Office 365 users although it should apply to all. http://terencerabe.wordpress.com/2011/05/21/calendar_sharing_office_365_beta/

Answer (score 0):

We have developed [an App](http://itunes.apple.com/app/colup-shared-exchange-items/id548633770?ls=1&mt=8&atleastcharacters=6) which enables iPhone users to open shared items (calendar, contacts and tasks) of other users. Also it is possible to create new items, if you have appropriate permissions on the shared users account.

Please note that you need iOS 5 (or higher) and Exchange 2007 SP2 (or higher).

Answer (score -1):

That cannot be done with Exchange/Outlook/ActiveSync alone.  ActiveSync only allows access to the primary account's Calendar(s)... ActiveSync is designed to sync the user's Outlook mailbox and nothing else.  If it could, then there'd be no need for those tools.  You might be able to use iTunes to sync that particular calendar, though....

Comment: To save anyone else looking, "Chapura's Pocket Mirror" is for Palm Pre, and related, devices, not the iPhone referred to in the question.

Comment: hasn't been edited by anyone. http://superuser.com/posts/62680/revisions